# lifting into a data type (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, lifting

```
type PT_Int = Int
type PT_String = String
data PolyType = PT_Int Int | PT_String String
```

Given a function f, how do I write a function that lifts it into PolyType? 
(just trying to understand lifting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PolyType` is equivalent to `Either Int String`. In case you haven't seen `Either` before:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

so you could have a function like

```
liftP :: (Either Int String -> a) -> PolyType -> a
liftP f poly = case poly of
    PT_Int    i -> f (Left i)
    PT_String s -> f (Right s)
```

`PolyType` contains either `Int` or `String`, so you can only lift functions that are defined over both `Int` and `String`.

That said, I don't think this is what you're after. The term "lifting" is usually used in the context of polymorphic data types like `[a]`, `Maybe a`, `(->) a` or in general some type `f a` where `f :: * -> *`.

In these cases, given a function `g :: a -> b`, you want a new function `[a] -> [b]`, `Maybe a -> Maybe b` or in general `f a -> f b`. This is exactly `fmap` from `Functor`.

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

but your `PolyType` is monomorphic (it doesn't have a free variable in its type. To be precise, it has kind `*`) so it can't be a `Functor`.

You chould change your definition of `PolyType` to

```
data PolyType a = PT a
```

Now this is a valid `Functor` (it's just the `Identity` `Functor`)

```
instance Functor PolyType where
    fmap f (PT a) = PT (f a)
```

The type of fmap (specialized for this particular `PolyType` instance) is

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> PolyType a -> PolyType b
```